# How can I monitor usage of an iPad that is probably stolen?

Tags: ipad, find-my-iphone

Someone may have stolen my iPad mini 2, or I've misplaced it. Checked on find my iPhone, and it shows up, but it stalls on "locating..." So, now I'm thinking how can I show use of the iPad via all the synced apps I have? It has cellular, and I can see data usage via my ISP, and it only shows my last known usage, nothing recent. I'm looking for a meta data solution to prove current use. If I can prove current use, then I know who has it. If it's just lost or misplaced with a dead battery or something, then nothing will show up.

Comment: The iPad shows up because you registered it. The Locating... message indicates it is not communicating by either Wifi or cell. Did you turn on Remote Erase and Activation Lock? If the battery is dead, its not going to communicate with the Find My iDevice services at all. Your other ideas, although they may have merit, don't make sense if the iPad is not connected.

Comment: @IconDaemon, I'm just looking for like something akin to a dyndns-updater type of solution. You know, like a log of device specific usage from automatically updating apps or something.

Answer (score 1):

If the isp has no data, you aren’t likely to get any better alternate than Apple lost mode / find my iPhone and pings from the cellular network.

If you truly think it’s stolen, consider filing a police report and send that to the carrier and ask for any pings.

Your reasoning is sound about the battery dead situation. In a few days, you’ll likely never hear again until someone powers it up or charges it near WiFi or cellular coverage.

Comment: Yeah, I have it on "notify when found," so we'll see.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I found it, so word to the wise, carseat.